# Enable Disable feature for Code Hide in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on optimizing an exe file which was developed in C#. I have changed some of the code which has increased performance but when I try to check-in the code to SVN source control my team told me that I could check in my code but I would have to hide my code by enabling and disabling functionality.

For example:

```
IF Code Hide == True  
   execute original Code
else 
   execute new code.
```

How can I do that for every change I have made?  Do I need to write an if-else statement in all the places I have changed the code? Please suggest how can I do that.

Comment: I guess you may mean hide your code stack during debug mode?

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of SVN?

Comment: Better to ask you manager or team. Before taking any problem to your hand,  be clear that what they asking to you to do.

Comment: Like Michael hinted at above in the comments: that's the whole point of a version control system. Why don't they let you create a branch with your version, and once it passes acceptance or qualification or whatever, you can merge your branch into the main trunk.  No point in doing extra work (and later again to remove the statements if you want your code to be clean).

Answer (score 3):

You should take advantage of the source control features of SVN. If you create a branch with your changes you can change the code and your team can switch between your code and their code at their leisure. If they are happy with your code they can merge your code into the main branch.

See: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way is unfortunately to write if-else statements all over the place.

It is possible to solve this by clever code design, like using the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and instantiate either a "normal" or "extended" version of the code, but that usually requires a lot of refactoring of your existing code.